# How to get SVM output as probability between 0 and 1?

Tags: r, svm, probability

I am using SVM for a binary modelling `(0,1)`. I use these codes for fitting the model and prediction:

```
fit=svm(Value~Slope+Aspect,data=Dataset,kernel="linear",cost=0.1,gamma=0.5)
pred=predict(fit,Total,probability=TRUE)
```

But the output has less than `0` (negative) and more than `1`. I need to have the probability between `0` and `1`.

Comment: What language are you using? Are you really using libsvm, svmsharp and svmlight?

Comment: No, I use e1071 package in R.

Comment: Binary modeling in sum is done with (-1,1) values, otherwise it is biased.

Comment: So, can't we get output as probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rtfm and you can retrieve the probabilities from the returned object. Please check the [manual](http://www.inside-r.org/node/57517) .

> probA, probB: numeric vectors of length k(k-1)/2, k number of classes,
>   containing the parameters of the logistic distributions fitted to the
>   decision values of the binary classifiers (1 / (1 + exp(a x + b))).

Also, the values -1 and 1 are maximum separation, they are not probabilities.